# UIPath - Get a single row of a datatable and write it in Excel

Tags: uipath

What's the best way on UIPATH to get a multi column row of a Datatable and to write it on Excel.

I'm in this situation :

- I converted an Excel table into a Datatable with **ExcelReadRange**
- I'm using a **ForEachRow** loop to get every row of my datatable
- inside this loop I'm using an **ExcelWriteRange** activity to write each row on the **same** range of my Excel File. (so yes I replace the row at each turn of my ForEachRow loop)

But I get the next error :

> Impossible to convert a **System.Data.DataRow** to a **System.Data.DataTable**

So I made a new Datatable with **BuildDataTable** and used **Add Data Row** and provided the target row. Thanks to that I can provid the new Datatable to my **ExcelWriteRange**.
But it's still not working and I get this new error :

> This row already belongs to another table

What's the solution to write row by row my datatable in Excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to provide the row as an ArrayRow and not as a DataRow to the **Add Data Row** activity

> DT_row.ItemArray